# Window is showing up, then dissapearing a second after

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to destroy the HWND I'm currently using, and open up a new window...

this is my code :

```
PostMessage(MainHwnd, WM_DESTROY, NULL, NULL); // Destroy the window
getClient() -> StartClient(); // Opening the client
```

where in StartClient I have:

```
RegisterMainClass(MainInstance); // Registaring the class
//Creating the Window
MainHwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE ,"MainClient", "Client", WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,  600, 500, NULL, NULL, MainInstance, NULL);

ShowWindow(MainHwnd, SW_SHOW);
UpdateWindow(MainHwnd);
```

So the window is destroyed, and the Client window shows up.. but the client window only shows up for about a second, and then dissapears again! Why is that? I have checked it couple of times, it actually creates the client window well, but it somehow hides it...

Also, I've checked with the WndProc of the Client Window,and it does reach the line of `return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);`

So what is going on? why is the window dissapearing right away?

I also have those 2 sections in my RoomProc :

```
        case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(1);
    break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
```

Comment: The answer lies in the code that we cannot see. It's time for an SSCCE.

Comment: As others noted, sending `WM_DESTROY` is not correct. In fact, calling `DestroyWindow` from your `WM_DESTROY` handler created an infinite loop. Eventually you get stack overflow and the process terminates.

Comment: @RaymondChen In all the examples I've seen, they have been calling DestroyWindow from the WM_DESTROY Handler... So how do I really suppost to do it ?

Comment: Look closely at the examples. They are destroying a different window from the one being destroyed. I.e. When window 1 is destroyed, then also destroy window 2. You didn't make it clear in the question but I'm guessing that you are having window 1 destroy itself which leads to recursion.

Comment: You're right. If I dont post the `DestroyWindow(hwnd)`, the program doesnt exit itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used both lines (destroying the window and create a new window) inside a thread, and therefor, it did problems to me. once I called the function normally and not in a different thread, everything went smooth...

Answer (score 2):

Don't post `WM_DESTROY` manually.  Use `DestroyWindow()` instead:

```
//PostMessage(MainHwnd, WM_DESTROY, NULL, NULL);
DestroyWindow(MainHwnd); // Destroy the window
```

Since you are going through the message queue, your `WM_DESTROY` message is delayed until new messages are processed at a later time, but by then your `MainHwnd` variable has changed value to point at the new window.  Besides, posting `WM_DESTROY` does not actually destroy the window, it merely notifies the window that it is being destroyed.

Comment: @Amit You need to go back to basics. When you call DestroyWindow, the system sends you a WM_DESTROY message. It's disappointing that you are concealing code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The parameter to PostMessage was the old handle. Changing the variable afterwards does not have any effect on the PostMessage. The problem is probably the infinite recursion in DestroyWindow. After a few seconds you hit stack overflow.

Comment: If DestroyWnbdow fails, it is probably because you are calling it from the wrong thread. Send a WM_CLOSE instead. (Also you need to figure out what your thread termination condition is. Right now it is in WM_CLOSE which is a strange place for it.)

Comment: @RaymondChen: the parameter to `PostMessage()` may be the old window, but since we cannot see what Amit's `WndProc()` is actually doing, for all we know Amit could be using the `MainHwnd` variable instead of using the `HWND` provided to the `WndProc`. In any case, you are certainly right about `DestroyWindow()` failing if called in the wrong thread context.